# Leaflet divIcon does not show up on map

Tags: leaflet, icons, mapbox, donut-chart

I am trying to make a custom marker using Leaflet's divIcon. Does anyone see problems with my code? When I run it with the normal default marker, it works fine. However, when I run it and try to use myIcon, no marker shows up. I've replaced my mapbox access token with *access_token*.

Any help would be great, thanks so much!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Donut Country View</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
     crossorigin=""/>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
      <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #map {
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 100%;
        }
        .donut {
          width: 20px;
          height: 20px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background-color: #E81D26;
          border: 4px solid #fff;
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px red, 0 0 0 10px white, 0 0 0 15px red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      var mapboxAccessToken = *access_token*;
      var map = L.map('map').setView([35.749907, -98.358421], 4);

      var tileL = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken, {
          id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
          tileSize: 512,
          zoomOffset: -1
      }).addTo(map);

      addCityMarker("Houston", [29.749907, -95.358421]); //plots Houston's city marker
      addCityMarker("Washington, D.C.", [38.8950, -77.0]); //plots DC's city marker

      var myIcon = L.divIcon({
        className: 'donut'
        //html: "<div class=\"donut\" ></div>"
      });

      function addCityMarker(name, center) { // plots a clickable marker, given a city's name and central coordinates.

        var city = L.marker(center, {
           icon: myIcon,
           title: name
        }).addTo(map);

        city.on('click', function(e){
            map.setView(e.latlng, 12);
        });
      }

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should very probably assign your `myIcon` variable *before* calling your `addCityMarker` function:

```js
  var myIcon = L.divIcon({
    className: 'donut'
    //html: "<div class=\"donut\" ></div>"
  });

  addCityMarker("Houston", [29.749907, -95.358421]); //plots Houston's city marker
  addCityMarker("Washington, D.C.", [38.8950, -77.0]); //plots DC's city marker
```